# mongodb mongoTemplate upsert

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I'm looking for ideas and solutions other people may have come up with to use upsert (or the like) to update a collection using MongoTemplate (if possible).

Below is a simple snippet: all I want to do is use "upsert" like functionality, where "items" represents an obj mapped to the collection.

```
for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
        mongoTemplate.insert(items.get(i));
}
```

Thanks for your help and happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an **update** is of the following form:

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

Where criteria specifies a document to update, objNew specifies the new document to replace the old one, upsert is a boolean that, when true, performs an upsert (if the record does not exist, create one), and multi is a boolean which tells mongo that all documents matching the criteria should be updated (not just one -- which is default)

I got that information from [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29)

I'm not familiar with MongoTemplate but I took a look at the docs and it seems their update function supports the upsert functionality. You should be able to use it by passing a true boolean value as the third parameter to your update call.

I saw this in the doUpdate method described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html)

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this potion.